# SARS-CoV virus stability at low temperatures

Tags: virology, temperature, coronavirus

For SARS-CoV-2 and SARS-CoV1 [this study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMc2004973) published in NEJM by a NIAID team was done at a temperature of 21-23°C (see the [Methods](https://www.nejm.org/doi/suppl/10.1056/NEJMc2004973/suppl_file/nejmc2004973_appendix.pdf) section in their supplemental material).

What's known about virus stability in general and for these two viruses specifically at much lower temperatures? (e.g. 4 °C, fridge temperature).

Comment: SE Biology is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes. General information about the coronavirus is available from a variety of reputable sources, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036). You are advised to consult them.